# Why can't I swap 2 variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to swap two variables in JavaScript, but my code does not work. Can anyone tell me why?

This should return 10, 5 I think, because I already called the swap function. But instead, it returns 5, 10.

```js
function swap(a, b) {
  var temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp
}

var x = 5;
var y = 10;
swap(x, y);
console.log(x, y);
```

Comment: x and y aren't passed by their ref, their values are copied in a and b

Comment: JavaScript passes arguments _by value_ (or "by sharing") not by reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript, like Java, is pass by reference only.  This means that while your function does swap the values, the actual values of `x` and `y` in the calling scope have not been swapped.  One workaround here might be to return an array of values, swapped:

```js
function swap(a, b) {
    return [b, a];
}

var x = 5;
var y = 10;
[x, y] = swap(x, y);
console.log("x after swap = " + x);
console.log("y after swap = " + y);
```

Note that here the critical line is the assignment:

```
[x, y] = swap(x, y);
```

This reassigns `x` and `y` to the swapped array in one line.

Comment: Note, this is the same as writing `var x = 5, y = 10; [x, y] = [y, x]`. Not much use for a function if you're going to rely on destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Destructuring assignment method:

```
let a = 1;
let b = 2;

[a, b] = [b, a];

a; // => 2
b; // => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function values aren't passed by reference, instead values get copied in a,b. So instead return values:

```
function swap(a, b) {
  return [b, a];
}
```

Later get it:

```
[x, y] = swap(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using JavaScript's objects, which passed by [*sharing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), similar to pass by reference you may have experienced in other languages. This allows you to do a few things that are not possible with primtive values -

```js
function ref (value) {
  return { value }
}

function deref (t) {
  return t.value
}

function set (t, value) {
  t.value = value
}

function swap (a, b) {
  const temp = deref(a)
  set(a, deref(b))
  set(b, temp)
}

const x = ref(3)
const y = ref(5)
swap(x,y)
console.log(deref(x), deref(y)) // 5 3
```

You can make this abstraction in any way you choose -

```js
const box = v => [v]
const unbox = t => t[0]
const set = (t, v) => t[0] = v

function swap (a, b) {
  const temp = unbox(a)
  set(a, unbox(b))
  set(b, temp)
}

const x = box(3)
const y = box(5)
swap(x,y)
console.log(unbox(x), unbox(y)) // 5 3
```

Comment: Objects are not passed by reference. They are passed ["by sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), which is a subcategory of passing by value.

Comment: Thanks for the technically correct term, though the wiki says it's not commonly used.